# MS Windows 10 Edge Live tiles system cache

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, live-tile, windows-10-desktop

I've changed paths (polling uri's) to `XML` with data but Windows still requests the old one xml url.

I was updating xml url in the following steps:

1. Turn live tiles off
2. Unpin tile
3. MS Edge browser cache and history clearing
4. Delete all content within C:/Users/**user_name**/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_**randomized_hash**/LocalState/PinnedTiles
5. Delete file **iconcache.db** inside C:/Users/**user_name**/AppData/Local
6. Disk Cleanup

So I start MS Edge again and pin tiles to start menu. Then I see that Windows still requests the old xml path via server logs.

How to update it? There must be some system cache I suppose ...

I've spent a lot of time and would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Support [replied](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/ms-windows-10-edge-live-tiles-system-cache/211d2327-b83b-4a61-be0b-84ed284be687) to my question. So the reason was MS Edge cache.

These steps helped me, I hope it'll help someone else.

> Please try the below steps to reset the edge browser and check. Please
>   know that resetting the Microsoft edge will remove your bookmarks and
>   History. Follow the instruction provided below and check.
>
> a. Navigate to the location:
>   **C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe**
>
> b. Delete everything in this folder.
>
> c. Type Windows Powershell in search box.
>
> d. Right click on Windows Powershell and select Run as administrator.
>
> e. Copy and paste the following command.
>
> **Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach
>   {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register
>   "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml" –Verbose}**

Answer (score 0):

The above worked for me. However, I have since discovered that after unpinning the tile/s you don't want, you can simply just delete the unrequired tile folder/s here: C:\Users\YOUR USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\PinnedTiles

Comment: It may work for static pins, but I had deal with dynamic ones. So the point was that they requested old url for data.

Answer (score 0):

Not to hijack the topic, but if you'd like to see all your bookmarks/favorites, here's a starter powershell script to give you that information.
You'll need the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`

```
    cls;
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Users\<YOUR USER FOLDER>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Newtonsoft.Json.dll") |Out-Null;

    $source = "C:\Users\<YOUR USER FOLDER>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\RoamingState";
    $filter = "{*}.json";

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $source -filter $filter -File;

    foreach ($f in $files)
    {
        $json = Get-Content -Path $f.FullName

        $result = [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::DeserializeObject($json);

        $result.Title.ToString()
        $result.URL.ToString()
    }
```